# How to deploy PHP files via composer?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to run php files on remote server.

I am asked to install them  via composer . I see on the files composer.json , composer.lock  but I have no clue how I can configure and run the files  :
The files I am trying to run are taken on this link https://github.com/borispavlov0/image-scrape

I am getting the below error when trying to run index.php file:

> Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php')

Comment: First you need to install Composer: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: Composer isn't a deploy tool. It's a dependency manager. It might be used _by_ a deploy tool, but it doesn't deploy anything itself.